# Elixir: Observables

Tags: stream, observablecollection, elixir

Elixir streams provide iterables, but I couldn't find any information on observables (Google was no help here). I'd greatly appreciate it if someone could point me to resources for the same.

Comment: Please describe the problem you need to solve. Perhaps an example in other language that uses an observable?

Comment: I want to build a client for a streaming api, but not use callbacks. Something similar to http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2014/01/turning-twitter4j-into-rxjavas.html

Comment: "observables"?  Elixir and Erlang both are deeply agent-based. It's hard to do much more with the concept of an observable than to have an agent-based architecture. Your question is analogous to standing beside a forest and asking where you can find lumber.

Comment: The conversation in this post is very useful to understand the different concepts and mindsets of Elixir. It should be a public wiki instead.

Answer (score 6):

You can combine Stream and Enum to write observable-style code. Here's an example of an echo server written in observable fashion:

```
IO.stream(:stdio, :line) 
|> Stream.map(&String.upcase/1)
|> Enum.each(&IO.write(&1))
```

Basically, for each line you send to standard input, it will be converted to uppercase and then printed back to standard output. This is a simple example, but the point is that all you need to compose an observable is already available via Stream and Enum.

Comment: To complement this response, languages using a "Observable-style" may provide a "subscribe" method/function that runs in another thread. In Elixir there is no need to such abstractions as you can easily spawn another process and generate/consume your stream in another process. For example, you could simply spawn the code above inside a new process: `spawn_link(fn -> ...code.above... end)`

Comment: I should also clarify that due to the push nature of Observable, there are a couple Observable actions like merge and take_until that are not supported by streams. However, Elixir enumerable are foldable and work well with resources, so the majority of the observable functionality *is* there.

Comment: @JoséValim I got the impression that OP was asking of something slightly different that being able to unfold a stream in another thread. See my answer.

Comment: @JoséValim your second comment answers my question perfectly. Feel free to add it as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5):

Streams in Elixir are abstractions over function composition. In the end, all you get is a function, calling which will loop over the input stream and transform it.

In order to build stateful streams like the example in Twitter4j (buffering new twitter statutes during one second and dispatching them all in one list), you'll need to use the building blocks that can have state. In Elixir, it is common to encapsulate state in processes.

The example might look like this

```
tweetsPerSecond =
  twitterStream 
  |> SS.buffer({1, :second}) 
  |> SS.map(&length(&1))

SS.subscribe(tweetsPerSecond, fn n -> IO.puts "Got #{n} tweets in the last second" end)
SS.subscribe(tweetsPerSecond, fn n -> IO.puts "Second subscriber" end)
```

`SS` is a new module we need to write to implement the observable functionality. The core idea (as far as I get it) is being able to subscribe to a stream without modifying it.

In order for this to work, the `twitterStream` itself should be a process emitting events for others to consume. You can't use `Stream` in this case because it has "blocking pull" semantics, i.e. you won't be able to interrupt waiting on the next element in a stream after some fixed amount of time has elapsed.

To achieve the equivalent functionality in Elixir, take a look at the [`GenEvent`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/master/elixir/GenEvent.html) module. It provides the ability to emit and subscribe to events. There is no stream-like interface for it though, not that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

I have built a PoC of a Pub-Sub system where I have followed a kind of "Observable Pattern": http://mendrugory.weebly.com/blog/pub-sub-system-in-elixir.

In order keep the state (what process has to be informed) I have used an [Agent](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Agent.html).